# How can i return TextView(id) as double?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

TextView layout

```
mTextValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount2);
```

To be able to get like this in another private void:

```
double amount= mTextValue;
```

XML

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/amount2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:hint="amount"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="15"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Total"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Total" />
```

I want to get the TextView and use it as double and return to be (return amount2 * 100);

Comment: If you want to take an input from the user, use ``EditText`` buddy. Why would you use ``TextView`` :(

Answer (score 1):

You get the value of `TextView` as `String`. You need to parse it into double.

```
Double.valueOf(mTextValue.getText());
```

You need to make sure the text in the `TextView` is a double, otherwise this method throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `TextView` use `EditText` to take input from a user:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/amount2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:hint="amount"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="15"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Total"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Total" />
```

And then to get the user input value use:

```
    final EditText amountEt = findViewById(R.id.amount2); // find the edit text
    final String userInput = amountEt.getText().toString(); // get the edittext value entered
final double amount;

if(!userInput.isEmpty()) {
  try {
    amount = Double.parseDouble(userInput);

    // do your calculations here and other stuffs

  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
} else {
    // show empty input message
  }
```